# Compute a series

Tags: java, math, series

Assignment: Write a method to compute the following series:
m(i) = 1 - (1/2) + (1/3) - (1/4) + (1/5) - ... + ((-1)^(i+1))/i

Write a test program that displays the following code:

```
i:       m(i):
5        0,78333
10       0,64563
..       ..
45       0,70413
50       0,68324
```

I've tried for a couple of hours now, and I just can't think of how to solve this. Maybe I'm just stupid haha :)

Here is my code so far:

```
package computingaseries;

public class ComputingASeries {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println("i\t\tm(i)");
        for (int i = 5; i <= 50; i += 5) {
            System.out.println(i + "\t\t" + m(i));
        }
    }
```

UPDATED:

```
    public static double m(int n) {
        double tal = 0;
        double x = 0;

        for (int i = 1; i <= n; i += 1) {
            if (i == 1) {
                x = 1 - ((Math.pow(-1, (i + 1))) / i);
            } else {
                x = ((Math.pow(-1, (i + 1))) / i);
            }
        }
        tal += x;

        return tal;

    }
}
```

My wrong output:

```
i       m(i)
5       0.2
10      -0.1
15      0.06666666666666667
20      -0.05
25      0.04
30      -0.03333333333333333
35      0.02857142857142857
40      -0.025
45      0.022222222222222223
50      -0.02
```

Comment: Hint, ^ isn't power like you think.

Comment: Also, the difference between integer division and floating point division is fundamental.

Comment: Math.pow working now, thanks :) But getting wrong output :/

Answer (score 2):

you have to eliminate the "1-" when you define x, i.e. x = ((-1)^(i+1))/i

**EDIT**

There is no special case for x==1, x is always defined as x=Math.pow(-1,i+1)/i. Note that ((-1)^(1+1))/1 = ((-1)^2)/1 = 1/1 = 1.
Also the tal +=x goes in the for-loop.

Comment: and also what Dan W answered is right, you have to use the correct operator for power

Comment: So I've eliminated the "1-" as you told me to, does it look alright now?

Comment: Math.pow working, but the output is totally messed up. Can you spot the problem? Updated code @ top :)

Comment: it is incorrect because the definition of x is always x = ((Math.pow(-1, (i + 1))) / i);
There is no special case for i==1, i.e. ((-1)^(1+1))/1 = ((-1)^2)/1 = 1/1 = 1, which is the first term of the series.
Also tal += x goes inside the for loop

Comment: There is no special case for any i. The code should look like this:   
        double tal = 0;
        double x = 0;

        for (int i = 1; i <= n; i += 1) {
            x = ((Math.pow(-1, (i + 1))) / i);
            tal += x;   
        }

Answer (score 0):

```
public class SpecialSeries {

    public static double m(int n){
        double sum = 0;
        for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
            sum += Math.pow(-1, (i+1))/(double)i;
        }  
        System.out.println(n+"\t"+sum);
        return sum;
    }  

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("i:\tm(i)");
        for (int i = 5; i < 50; i+=5) {
            m(i);
        }
    }
}
```

you can run it here at [ideone](http://ideone.com/KllkQ3)